# SCIP: integrality tolerance parameter

Tags: limit, scip

In SCIP 3.2.1 MILP solver, what is the parameter for a variable's integrality tolerance? I haven't found one in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether a variable is considered integer is up to the *integrality constraint handler*. That also means that there is no dedicated integrality tolerance, instead you need to set the general feasibility tolerance `numerics/feastol`.